# R "RPostgrSQL" package fails to install on Centos 8 (as `lib` is unspecified)

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, r, centos-8

I want to install the R package RPostgresql to connect to my PostgreSQL database called "crex" on Centos 8. When I run

```
> install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
```

in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("RPostgreSQL") :
  'lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel)
```

From the message I am gathering that I need to setup a personal library but I am not sure about the implications. What I am trying to do is run a r script e.g. new.r that will be called from another bash script.

new.r:

```
require("RPostgreSQL")

pw <- {
  "XXXX"
}

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "crex",
                 host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                 user = "postgres", password = pw)
rm(pw) 

dbExistsTable(con, "work")
#other commands
```

Bash script b.txt:

```
#!/bin/bash

Rscript new.r
#other commands
```

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R wants to install packages in that default path. Either that path doesn't exist or you don't have write access to it.

It is not a problem (from the standpoint of you running an R script via bash) to have the libraries installed elsewhere (e.g. in a personal library). I wouldn't worry about where the libraries are installed, unless you have a particular problem loading them later. One possible implication is that if you run the script from a different user, then you may need to install again into a path that is accessible by that user.

Comment: Thanks 5rrrrr for taking the time!